# Show one row per group (grouped values from table1) with comma separated distinct list from table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

For this example, I run a small company and am also secretly a vampire.

I'd like to know which department has the most variety of blood types, as variety is the spice of the afterlife, and in addition to being a monster that feasts on the blood of my employees I'm also lazy, so I'd like to maximize the variety for my departmental visits.

*empbloods*

| Name | BloodType | EmployeeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arvid | O+ | Ar1 |
| Beatrice | A- | Be1 |
| Cilla | O+ | Ci1 |
| Desmond | AB- | De1 |
| Evelyn | A+ | Ev1 |
| Francis | A- | Fr1 |
| Gayle | O+ | Ga1 |
| Hector | AB+ | He1 |

*empdeps*

| Department | EmployeeID |
| --- | --- |
| Finance | Ar1 |
| Admin | Be1 |
| Finance | Ci1 |
| Finance | De1 |
| Admin | Ev1 |
| Admin | Fr1 |
| Admin | Ga1 |
| Finance | Ga1 |
| Admin | He1 |

How do I write a SQL Server query so that I get one row per department, with a comma separated list of the *distinct* blood types within each department.

| dept | distinctBloodTypes |
| --- | --- |
| Finance | O+,AB- |
| Admin | A-,A+,O+,AB+ |

Bonus if the same query can have an additional column for total of employees in the department:

| dept | distinctBloodTypes | EmpTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | O+,AB- | 4 |
| Admin | A-,A+,O+,AB+ | 5 |

I made [one of these fiddle things](https://dbfiddle.uk/jSGYL7St) for my super-simple attempt that is so close but is showing blood types for every employee, rather than just the distinct blood types.

```
select ed.Department as Deps, STRING_AGG(eb.BloodType,',') as DistBloodTypes
from empbloods eb
left join empdeps ed ON eb.EmployeeID=ed.EmployeeID
group by ed.Department
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Great question, how about this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/uBU881cs

Comment: If you convert your images to tabular markdown this becomes a good question... till then its not.

Comment: I dunno guys, the fiddle should be enough, the images are just extra info

Comment: @siggemannen Ideally the question should be self-contained also, as sometimes the fiddle site goes down. This doesn't need window functions.

Comment: @siggemannen We should be able to see everything we need to provide an answer without having to click a single link. Anything else is a bonus.

Comment: Fair enough, updated to tables. I assumed the images would be viewable inline. Agree that having to click out is annoying.

Comment: Even if the images are viewable (they can be made so) you still shouldn't post them. They can't be copied into a fiddle or into SSMS, they can't be tested, and you can't view them properly in the mobile app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to aggregate then aggregate again.

```sql
select
  e.Department as Deps,
  STRING_AGG(e.BloodType, ',') as DistBloodTypes,
  COUNT(*) as CountDistinctBloodTypes,
  SUM(e.count) as TotalCount
from (
    select
      ed.Department,
      eb.BloodType,
      COUNT(*)  as count
    from empbloods eb
    left join empdeps ed ON eb.EmployeeID=ed.EmployeeID
    group by
      ed.Department,
      eb.BloodType
) e
group by
  e.Department;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/uBU881cs)

Comment: LEGEND! Thank you!!! Time to feast!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to see the count for each blood type:

```
select Department as Deps
  , string_agg(BloodType + '('+cast(cnt as varchar)+')', ',')
      within group (order by cnt desc, BloodType) as DistBloodTypes 
  , sum(cnt) AS EmplTotal
from (select ed.Department, eb.BloodType, count(*) as cnt
  from empbloods eb
  left join empdeps ed on eb.EmployeeID=ed.EmployeeID
  group by ed.Department, eb.BloodType) x
group by Department
```

[db<>fillde](https://dbfiddle.uk/NXYT2uF1)

| Deps | DistBloodTypes | EmplTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Admin | A-(2),A+(1),AB+(1),O+(1) | 5 |
| Finance | O+(3),AB-(1) | 4 |

Comment: AWESOME! What a cool upgrade!